# Socket errors when the number of threads above a certain level flow

Tags: c#, sockets, exception

Good afternoon. I apologize for my English as itself from Ukraine and speak badly)) I have the following problem, my program makes requests on different urls and then parse some info from answers. Number of urls are more than several millions. To quickly process I use a lot of threads, sometimes about 500-700 threads. On some machines program is running well, but there are those on which errors occur. Errors like: `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): The remote host forcibly broke the existing connection.`

**My code:**

```
void _thread()
{
while(true)
{
string request =
"POST http://" + hostf + "/ HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
"Host: " + host +
"\r\nConnection: Close\r\n" +
"Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n" +
"Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3\r\n" +
"Content-Length: " + ByteArr.Length +
"\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n" +
parametres;

Byte[] bytesSent = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(request);
Byte[] bytesReceived = new Byte[256];
Socket s = null;
IPHostEntry hostEntry = null;
hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(host);
foreach (IPAddress address in hostEntry.AddressList)
{
IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(address, 80);
Socket tempSocket =new Socket(ipe.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
tempSocket.Connect(ipe);
if (tempSocket.Connected)
{
s = tempSocket;
break;
}
else
{
continue;
}
}
if (s == null)
continue;
s.Send(bytesSent, bytesSent.Length, 0);
int bytes = 0;
string page = "";
do
{
bytes = s.Receive(bytesReceived, bytesReceived.Length, 0);
page = page + Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetString(bytesReceived, 0, bytes);
}
while (bytes > 0);
s.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
s.Close();
//here some work whith page content
}
}
```

As you see, each thread creates socket, sends request, then get answer and closes socket and so on with each iteration. Each thread opens its own socket and works with different urls, but on some machines when numbers of threads are more than some number, the errors begin and all sockets don't work normally. Could someone help me with some advise, why does it happen? Some machines have some kind of limits on connection or what? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: In case of `SocketException` you've to refer [Socket Errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `SocketException.ErrorCode` property.

Answer (score 0):

Dont do the shutdown(both); followed by a close. Remove the s.shutdown() and leave the s.Close() then try. I think I remeber that shutdown both makes the socket descriptor available for use so in the next close you can be closing some other socket instead the one you owned.

EDIT: some code modification:

I'd increment a little bit the receive buffer

```
bytes[] bytesReceived = new bytes[1024];
```

Also when sending the request string tell the reciver you are done:

```
s.Send(bytesSent, bytesSent.Length, 0);
// Tell the receiver we are done sending data
s.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);
```

You also have to check for error when reading the socket and use a StringBuilder instead of a String (it's somehow faster than String appending text):

```
StringBuilder page = new StringBuilder();
do
{
    bytes = s.Receive(bytesReceived, bytesReceived.Length, 0);
    if (bytes == -1)
    {
         // Error in socket, quit
         s.Close();
         return;
    }
    else if (bytes > 0)
         page.Append(Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetString(bytesReceived, 0, bytes));
}
while (bytes > 0);
```

At the end, just close the socket:

```
// s.ShutDown(Socketshutdown.Both);
s.close();
```

You may try with this modifications and see if it is solved.

Comment: Could you show sample please how to build the code for my request for correct sockets work?

Comment: There are a lot of SocketException.ErrorCode 10060 Connection timed out. A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or the established connection failed because the connected host has failed to respond.

Comment: I have noticed that the more threads works the more exceptions appear. When number of thread about 10-20 there are no exceptions at all. So i think this problem somehow depends on number of connections that sockets open...

Comment: Iam out of the city & using a phone. Tomorrow I'll take a look at your code.

Comment: @user2626154 can you post more code, what do you do in the "some work with page" in the bottom of the thread, and how you break the while (true) loop? See my answer for some more comments.